# Can mongodb be used as a data source for google charts?

Tags: json, mongodb, google-visualization

Is it possible to use mongodb as a data source for google charts?
Any examples or tutorials of this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is most definitely possible.

A quick Google search: `mongodb google charts` gave me (for example) the following links:

- [ikanow](http://www.ikanow.com/2013/03/19/how-to-visualize-json-documents-from-mongodb/)
- [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongo-db-washington-dc-2013)

Hope this helps you out